# Add Audio and Hyperlink to Image On Click

Tags: html, image, audio, hyperlink, onclick

I am working on a site for a client, and he specifically requested that we tie audio clips of this character speaking to images of said character so that when you click the image of the character, it plays one of his trademark phrases.

In addition to that, some of the images also need to contain a hyperlink, so when you click the image, it plays audio AND links you to another page.

I have been successful in linking the audio to the image, and adding a hyperlink to an image is nothing new, but I cannot for the life of me get them both to work at the same time!

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: While possible, you may need a lot more to do then just adding a hyperlink. When you open a link in `"_self"`, your current page got "discarded" and thus stopping any playing media on it. To archive a "concurrent" effect, you may need JS (and AJAX) to rebuild your page, instead of actually opening a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else asked this question and was directed to http://jplayer.org/ which is an opensource player with various guides on how to implement it, including various integrated Javascript functions that, I imagine, can be used within an 'onclick' function..

-- The question: [Play mp3 file with javascript onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766538/play-mp3-file-with-javascript-onclick)